# ListView: 1st Item of the listview affects its last item

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, getview

i have a listview populated by two button and a textview. The problem is that every time I change the value to the last textview of my listview it resets the first, and if I change the first it resets the last. I also tried to use the tags and then compare them, but it doesn't work anyway. I don't understand where the problem is. Could anyone help me?

```js
public class ProductListAdapterforListView extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<piatto> mProductList;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    int[] bStatus;

    public ProductListAdapterforListView(Context mContext, List<piatto> mProductList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mProductList = mProductList;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        bStatus = new int[mProductList.size()];

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mProductList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mProductList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Viewholder viewholder;
        View row=convertView;
        if (row == null){
            viewholder=new Viewholder();

            row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_data_list, parent, false);


            viewholder.nome= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.namepiatto);
            viewholder.imageView= (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imagepiatto);
            viewholder.prezzo= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.prezzopiatto);
            viewholder.btntakemore=(Button) row.findViewById(R.id.takemore);
            viewholder.btntakeless=(Button) row.findViewById(R.id.takeoff);
            viewholder.textViewcount=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.count);

            viewholder.btntakemore.setTag(position);
            viewholder.btntakeless.setTag(position);
            viewholder.textViewcount.setTag(position);

            row.setTag(viewholder);

        } else {
            viewholder = (Viewholder) row.getTag();
        }

        viewholder.nome.setText(mProductList.get(position).getNome());
        viewholder.prezzo.setText(mProductList.get(position).getPrezzo());
        Picasso.get().load(mProductList.get(position).getImmagine()).into(viewholder.imageView);

        viewholder.btntakemore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int v= (int) viewholder.btntakemore.getTag();
                int v1= (int) viewholder.textViewcount.getTag();

                if (v==v1){
                    int val= Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(viewholder.textViewcount.getText()));
                    if (val < 5){
                        val=val + 1;
                        viewholder.textViewcount.setText(String.valueOf(val));
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }

            }
        });


        viewholder.btntakeless.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int v= (int) viewholder.btntakeless.getTag();
                int v1= (int) viewholder.textViewcount.getTag();

                if (v==v1){
                    int val= Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(viewholder.textViewcount.getText()));
                    if (val < 5){
                        val=val + 1;
                        viewholder.textViewcount.setText(String.valueOf(val));
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return row;
    }

    public class Viewholder {
        TextView nome;
        TextView prezzo;
        ImageView imageView;
        Button btntakemore, btntakeless;
        TextView textViewcount;
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to update the array list value, not do `settext`. SetText will work as long as you dont scroll. Once you scroll the view is updated with the array. As your array value has not changed, the textview value is not changed.

Comment: I really thank you for your attention.
So are you telling me that I have to save each value in 'int[ ] bstatus' and set the text via the array? forgive me but I'm inexperienced

Comment: I do not know what bstatus is but you need to update the mproductList[index] name as far as i can tell from the code

Comment: Ah, I understand. I try to do as you told me. Thanks so much!!